# How to update array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am struggling to find a suitable logic to update this array in Laravel. With this same logic, I can create however with I try to update It does only update all rows of the array.

**I do not want to update anything right now. I only enter the edit page. I get this error**

Thanks

[image: filters table]

**FilterController.php**

```
public function edit(Filter $filter)
{
    $colors = Color::all();
    $categories = Category::lists();
    $filters = Filter::with('category')->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($filter){
        $query->whereIn('category_id', [$filter->category_id]);
    })->get();
    return view('Admin.filters.edit', compact('categories', 'colors', 'filter', 'filters'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Filter $filter)
{
    dd('ok');
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('filters.update', $filter->whereIn('category_id', [$filter->id])) }}">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
```

Comment: can you please add more details ? 
what have you tried ? i don't see any update command in your controller ? what do you want to update exactly

Comment: what is this ? - `route('filters.update', $filter->whereIn('category_id', [$filter->id]))`

Comment: @MasudulHasanShawon When I change this `route('filters.update', $filter->id)` I get this error https://laraveldaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Screen-Shot-2019-05-07-at-4.35.18-PM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function edit(Filter $filter)
{
    $colors = Color::all();

    $categories = Category::lists();

    $filters = Filter::with('category')->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($filter){

        $query->whereIn('category_id', [$filter->category_id]);

    })->get(); // I'm not sure what do you want by this instead of $filter->load('category');

    return view('Admin.filters.edit', compact('categories', 'colors', 'filter', 'filters'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd('ok');
}
```

**Blade File**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('filters.update', $filter->id) }}">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
```

Isn't it you're looking for?